# How to run a function every hour, while the android app is in the background?

Tags: java, android, mobile, notifications

i'm developing a software using Google Maps and i need a code to run the foreach below, while it's in the onPause or onStop cycle every hour. If possible run in other modes, but doing the same function, I accept suggestions.

```
for(i = id; i <= amountDB; i++){

            dayI = alerts.ConverterDAY(i);
            hourI = alerts.ConverterHOUR(i);

        if(hourI == hour && dayI == day) {
            NotificationMaps();
        }else if(hourI == hour && dayI == day) {
            NotificationMaps();
        }else if(hourI == hour && dayI == day) {
            NotificationMaps();
        }
   }
```

Basically, it is a notification that will only run at the times saved in the user database.
Example: If for hourI = 7 and hour = 7, it will notify. 
But the foreach is for it to traverse all data saved in the user database. So at every hour, I would like it to check in the database if the saved data is equal to the time on the device to notify the user.

Comment: use alarm manager for that also set the alarm when device reboot

Comment: Set `repeating alarm` using alarm manager and set `broadcast receiver` for pending intent. Alarm call every hour to that receiver where you can add your work. Or instead of `receiver` you can use `service`.

Answer (score 0):

**Lollipop and above:**
Use JobScheduler: [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

**Below Lollipop:**
Use JobSchedularCompat: [Link](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat)
Use AlarmManager: [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)